# Error: Quota exceeded for quota metric - pagespeed googleapis

Tags: google-api, pagespeed, google-pagespeed-insights-api, sitespeedio

I am running [sitespeed docker container](https://www.sitespeed.io/documentation/sitespeed.io/docker/) container and using config file to run multiple pages at a time. I've also scheduled it to run every hour but from the job output I am seeing the below error related to some Quote Exceeded

```
[2021-11-02 01:16:58] ERROR: Error: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute' of service 'pagespeedonline.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:583797351490'.
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> (/gpsi/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:72:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/gpsi/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:16:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Any ides on what this could be and how can we fix this? In the coming future I would be testing around 100 pages using this and I am sure it would fail as well with this error

sitespeed.io docker container command -

```
docker run --shm-size=1g --rm -v "$(pwd):/sitespeed.io" $DOCKER_IMAGE --graphite.addSlugToKey true --slug shasha_test --config configs.json urls.txt
```

The error which I am getting is below. So it works for some pages and then fails for others. How do i check the quota here?

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for XXXXXX.XXX.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/sitespeedio/sitespeedio:latest
Google Chrome 92.0.4515.131 
Mozilla Firefox 92.0b2
Microsoft Edge 92.0.902.8 dev
[2021-11-02 01:16:57] INFO: Versions OS: linux 4.14.248-189.473.amzn2.x86_64 nodejs: v14.17.1 sitespeed.io: 19.1.0 browsertime: 14.0.2 coach: 6.4.3
[2021-11-02 01:16:58] INFO: Will run Lighthouse tests after Browsertime has finished
[2021-11-02 01:16:58] INFO: Sending url https://www.virginmedia.com to test on Page Speed Insights
[2021-11-02 01:16:58] INFO: Sending url https://www.virginmedia.com/broadband/packages to test on Page Speed Insights
[2021-11-02 01:16:58] INFO: Sending url https://www.virginmedia.com/broadband to test on Page Speed Insights
[2021-11-02 01:16:58] INFO: Sending url https://www.virginmedia.com/broadband/speed-test to test on Page Speed Insights
[2021-11-02 01:16:58] ERROR: Error: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute' of service 'pagespeedonline.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXXXXXX'.
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> (/gpsi/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:72:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/gpsi/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:16:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
[2021-11-02 01:16:58] ERROR: Error: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute' of service 'pagespeedonline.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXXXXXX'.
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> (/gpsi/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:72:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/gpsi/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:16:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 1):

Quota is the number of requests that your application can make to an api.  This is normally split up in per day or per minute quotas.

If you check your project on Google cloud console under libray.  There and search for PageSpeed Insights API you have  already enabled it. click manage then you come to a new screen where you will find quota on the left.

This is the limit of requests that you can make to the api per day and per minute.

[image]

You are exceding the **Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute'** quota which is technically flood protection your going to fast slow down your application. you can only make 240 requests a minute.

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you for the quick response. So that's the thing. I am running this in a container on AWS cloud. I've edit my question to include the docker command which I am using. If you see at the end ```urls.txt``` it contains all the URL's which I would like sitespeed to run.